# TStringList always doing line break

Tags: delphi

I'm developing a hook for keyboard and using SetWindowsHookEx and I add every keystroke inside a TStringList. To manipulate the keystrokes inside the TStringList I'm always using the '.Text' property. To add the typed keystrokes for example I use:

> KeyStrokes.Text:= KeyStrokes.Text + AChr;

If I detect a [backspace] then I try to delete the last character in the StringList using:

> KeyStrokes.Text := Copy(KeyStrokes.Text, 1, length(KeyStrokes.Text) -
>   1);

All this was working while I added inside a TMemo using the same '.Text' property. But since when I put in TStringList, in the saved Log.txt file (using .SaveToFile property) I'm getting the logs like this:

H

E

L

L

O

Instead of 'Hello'. I tried '.Append', '.Add' properties and always the same. And of course, the backspace deleting the last letter doesn't work anymore... How to put keystrokes correctly? Is that even possible to do in TStringList?

Comment: Why would you even want to use a StringList if there's never more than one String?

Comment: And what version of Delphi are we talking about?

Comment: Delphi 2010... And the problem about using a simple string variable is just commented below in other answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TStringList` doesn't appear to be the right tool for the job, at least not if you're going to use the `Text` property. As you know from the documentation, reading the `Text` property joins all the items in the list with line breaks. Writing to that property *splits* the new value at each line break and creates a separate entry in the list for each item.

If you're trying to keep track of keystrokes, you don't want your data structure to silently munge your data by inserting and removing things that look like keystrokes but that don't represent real keystrokes. (In particular, note that reading the `Text` property will *append* a line break at the end of the result. That affects your backspace logic.)

Use a plain old string to keep track of the current state of the string input.

Comment: The problem about using a simple string is because same way I was deleting the last character when I detect a [backspace], I was doing a line break when detect [enter], and I'll lose this feature with a simple string variable. There's no other class that I can use just like a TMemo? Easy to manipulate / save to file, but only in memory... Like TStringStream, can work?

Comment: `TMemo` uses a `TStrings` descendant that stores the string data in the Memo's window. `TStringList` is a `TStrings` descendant that stores string data in memory.  The problem you are encountering is occurring in `TStrings` itself, not its descendants, so you should be experiencing the same problem regardless of what type of `TStrings`-based object you use.

Answer (score 2):

The only way the `TStringList` could be saving line breaks to the file is if the `TStringList` has multiple strings in it when you call `SaveToFile()`.  The reason is because reading the `Text` property inserts an implicit line break at the end, which are not stripping off before writing back to the `Text`. So each keystroke ends up as a new string in the list.

Like everyone else said, `TStringList` is the wrong tool for this job in the first place.  Use a simple `String` instead:

```
KeyStrokes: String;
...
KeyStrokes := KeyStrokes + AChr;
...
Delete(KeyStrokes, Length(KeyStrokes), 1);
```

Comment: I think the TStringList is adding line break not because have multiple strings, but because each key pressed the hook procedure start again, key by key, so the TStringList identify like a new 'string', even if is just another key in the same string... And the problem about using a simple string is because same way I was deleting the last character when I detect a [backspace], I was doing a line break when detect [enter], and I'll lose this feature with a simple string variable. There's no way to do this using TStringStream or anything?

Comment: You are already reading/writing a single string, just one that the `TStringList` manages. Switching to a single `String` variable will not cause you to lose any functionality at all.

Answer (score 1):

It really seems far more practical to use a normal **string**. In a comment you were concerned about losing some functionality, saying: "I was doing a line break when detect [enter]". You can easily support this with normal strings by appending `sLineBreak` a constant for the End-Of-Line (EOL) marker. On Windows, this equals `#13#10` (a carriage return and line feed). The only thing you'd need to watch out for is that when you use backspace to delete the EOL, you need to delete the correct number of characters: 2 for Windows, 1 for Linux/MAC. `Length(sLineBreak)` would tell you how many.

Another option you may want to consider is the `TStringBuilder` class. It is designed to build up strings piece-meal, so may suite your purposes.

Finally, if you really want to use `TStringList`, you can manipulate the strings individually (i.e. not using the `Text` property):

```
FInputData: TStrings;
FInputData := TStringList.Create;
FInputData.Add(''); { Important to always have at least 1 string }

{ When adding a character "Ch" }
FInputData[FInputData.Count-1] := FInputData[FInputData.Count-1] + Ch;

{ When detecting the Enter Key }
FInputData.Add('');

{ When detecting Backspace }
S := FInputData[FInputData.Count-1];
if (S <> '') then
begin
  { Delete last character on current line }
  Delete(S, Length(S), 1);
  FInputData[FInputData.Count-1] := S;
end
else if (S = '') and (FInputData.Count > 1) then
begin
  { Go back to previous line if current is empty, but don't delete if 
    there's nothing left. (Remember: always have at least 1 string) }
  FInputData.Delete(FInputData.Count-1);
end;

{ To write the current data }
Writeln(FInputData.Text);
```